# How to show custom xml text contents in tree

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an xml file it's structure like down below :

```
<Bookmark>
  <Title Action="GoTo" Page="14 FitH 670" >1. internal diseases
    <Title Action="GoTo" Page="14 FitH 463" >gastroesophageal reflu
</Title>
    <Title Action="GoTo" Page="15 FitH 600" >gastritis
</Title>
    <Title Action="GoTo" Page="15 FitH 215" >peptic ulcer
</Title>...
```

I looked for couple of examples It uses Xml attributes to shows as tree components' labels. But I want to show these xml text contents in tree component. But i couldn't find an example how to show as label these xml text contents. Hope you can help me out to find a solution thanks.

Comment: http://www.air-tutorial.com/tree-xml-flex-air - This link may help you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the contents of an XML node, navigate to the desired node using the E4X standards built in to as3. A great resource for this is the following site: http://dispatchevent.org/roger/as3-e4x-rundown/

The following is an example of how to trace the contents of the `<Title>` node with the attribute `"15 FitF 600"`:

```
var xml:XML = 
<Bookmark>
  <Title Action="GoTo" Page="14 FitH 670" >1. internal diseases</Title>
  <Title Action="GoTo" Page="14 FitH 463" >gastroesophageal reflu</Title>
  <Title Action="GoTo" Page="15 FitH 600" >gastritis</Title>
  <Title Action="GoTo" Page="15 FitH 215" >peptic ulcer</Title>
</Bookmark>

trace (xml.Title.(@Page == "15 FitH 600")); //gastritis
trace (xml.Title.(@Page == "15 FitH 600").toString()); //gastritis
trace (xml.Title.(@Page == "15 FitH 600").valueOf()); //gastritis
trace (xml.Title.(@Page == "15 FitH 600").toXMLString()); //<Title Action="GoTo" Page="15 FitH 600">gastritis</Title>
```